# How to train IBM Watson Assistant to answer from a specific dataset (say a eBook)?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant, watson-ml

I am a new bee to IBM Watson. I went through videos to create virtual assistant/chatbot where we could define intents/entities and answer accordingly. This seems fine when I have limited number of intents/entities. But say, I have a eBook and I want to train Watson to answer from this eBook. How do I achieve this. Anyone high level approach or direction will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different approaches.

You could use the integrated [search skill](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-skills) which provides a link to Watson Discovery. You would upload your eBook to Watson Discovery and kind of index it.

Another approach is to use a database or something else as backend. Based on the input which identifies the search term and scopes which eBook to search, the answer would be retrieved from the backend database. This [tutorial features a Db2 database and Watson Assistant retrieves the answer from the database](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/solution-tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-slack-chatbot-database-watson). A similar approach is taken in this [sample which shows how to retrieve excerpts from Wikipedia](https://github.com/data-henrik/chatbot-talks/tree/2020letsmake).